# Using boost::icl::interval_map with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, boost-icl

I'd like to use shared pointers with `boost::icl::interval_map`, something similar to the following:

```
namespace icl = boost::icl;
icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::string>> party;
const auto mary = std::make_shared<const std::string>("Mary");
party += make_pair(icl::interval<int>::right_open(10, 16), mary);
```

The `std::shared_ptr` actually points to an abstract class (not `std::string` as in the example) that must be referred to via a pointer (hence the problem).

Below are some of the compiler errors the snippet above produces. It looks like template deduction is failing, but it's not clear to me which of the many overloads the compiler *should* be using. Can anyone more familiar with ICL (or reading these errors) explain what is going on in English?

```
Scanning dependencies of target SourceFile
[100%] Building CXX object SourceFile.cpp.o
In file included from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/map.hpp:38:0,
                 from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:25,
                 from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_map.hpp:14,
                 from /home/user/SourceFile.cpp:1:
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/functors.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::icl::inplace_plus<Type>::operator()(Type&, const Type&) const [with Type = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’:
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:898:19:   required from ‘void boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::add_rear(const interval_type&, const CodomainT&, boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator&) [with Combiner = boost::icl::inplace_plus<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::interval_type = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:968:27:   required from ‘boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::_add(const segment_type&) [with Combiner = boost::icl::inplace_plus<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:315:9:   required from ‘SubType& boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::add(const segment_type&) [with SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_map.hpp:149:30:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_interval_map<Type>, Type>::type& boost::icl::add(Type&, const typename Type::segment_type&) [with Type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_interval_map<Type>, Type>::type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename Type::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_associator.hpp:305:20:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type& boost::icl::operator+=(Type&, const OperandT&) [with Type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; OperandT = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/home/user/SourceFile.cpp:96:68:   required from here
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/functors.hpp:73:18: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘const std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’)
         { object += operand; }
           ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/associative_interval_container.hpp:18:0,
                 from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_set.hpp:24,
                 from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_set.hpp:14,
                 from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_map.hpp:13,
                 from /home/user/SourceFile.cpp:1:
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_associator.hpp:303:1: note: candidate: template<class Type, class OperandT> typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type& boost::icl::operator+=(Type&, const OperandT&)
 operator += (Type& object, const OperandT& operand)
 ^~~~~~~~
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_associator.hpp:303:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_associator.hpp: In substitution of ‘template<class Type, class OperandT> typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type& boost::icl::operator+=(Type&, const OperandT&) [with Type = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; OperandT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’:
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/functors.hpp:73:18:   required from ‘void boost::icl::inplace_plus<Type>::operator()(Type&, const Type&) const [with Type = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:898:19:   required from ‘void boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::add_rear(const interval_type&, const CodomainT&, boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator&) [with Combiner = boost::icl::inplace_plus<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::interval_type = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:968:27:   required from ‘boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::_add(const segment_type&) [with Combiner = boost::icl::inplace_plus<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:315:9:   required from ‘SubType& boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::add(const segment_type&) [with SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_map.hpp:149:30:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_interval_map<Type>, Type>::type& boost::icl::add(Type&, const typename Type::segment_type&) [with Type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_interval_map<Type>, Type>::type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename Type::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_associator.hpp:305:20:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type& boost::icl::operator+=(Type&, const OperandT&) [with Type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; OperandT = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/home/user/SourceFile.cpp:96:68:   required from here
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_associator.hpp:303:1: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’
In file included from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/associative_interval_container.hpp:18:0,
                 from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_set.hpp:24,
                 from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_set.hpp:14,
                 from /ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_map.hpp:13,
                 from /home/user/SourceFile.cpp:1:
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/functors.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::icl::inplace_plus<Type>::operator()(Type&, const Type&) const [with Type = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’:
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:898:19:   required from ‘void boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::add_rear(const interval_type&, const CodomainT&, boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator&) [with Combiner = boost::icl::inplace_plus<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::interval_type = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:968:27:   required from ‘boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::_add(const segment_type&) [with Combiner = boost::icl::inplace_plus<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:315:9:   required from ‘SubType& boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::add(const segment_type&) [with SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_map.hpp:149:30:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_interval_map<Type>, Type>::type& boost::icl::add(Type&, const typename Type::segment_type&) [with Type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_interval_map<Type>, Type>::type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename Type::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_associator.hpp:305:20:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type& boost::icl::operator+=(Type&, const OperandT&) [with Type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; OperandT = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/home/user/SourceFile.cpp:96:68:   required from here
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_associator.hpp:318:1: note: candidate: template<class Type, class OperandT> typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_combinable<LeftT, RightT>, Type>::type& boost::icl::operator+=(Type&, const OperandT&)
 operator += (Type& object, const OperandT& operand)
 ^~~~~~~~

... more "template argument deduction/substitution failed" errors ...

/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/element_associator.hpp:192:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/element_associator.hpp: In substitution of ‘template<class Type> typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_associative_element_container<Type>, Type>::type& boost::icl::operator+=(Type&, const Type&) [with Type = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’:
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/functors.hpp:73:18:   required from ‘void boost::icl::inplace_plus<Type>::operator()(Type&, const Type&) const [with Type = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:898:19:   required from ‘void boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::add_rear(const interval_type&, const CodomainT&, boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator&) [with Combiner = boost::icl::inplace_plus<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::interval_type = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:968:27:   required from ‘boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::_add(const segment_type&) [with Combiner = boost::icl::inplace_plus<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/interval_base_map.hpp:315:9:   required from ‘SubType& boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::add(const segment_type&) [with SubType = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; DomainT = int; CodomainT = std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Traits = boost::icl::partial_absorber; Compare = std::less; Combine = boost::icl::inplace_plus; Section = boost::icl::inter_section; Interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>; Alloc = std::allocator; boost::icl::interval_base_map<SubType, DomainT, CodomainT, Traits, Compare, Combine, Section, Interval, Alloc>::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_map.hpp:149:30:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_interval_map<Type>, Type>::type& boost::icl::add(Type&, const typename Type::segment_type&) [with Type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_interval_map<Type>, Type>::type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename Type::segment_type = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/interval_associator.hpp:305:20:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type& boost::icl::operator+=(Type&, const OperandT&) [with Type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; OperandT = std::pair<boost::icl::discrete_interval<int, std::less>, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >; typename boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_intra_derivative<Type, AssociateT>, Type>::type = boost::icl::interval_map<int, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
/home/user/SourceFile.cpp:96:68:   required from here
/ext-lib/include/boost/icl/concept/element_associator.hpp:192:1: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::enable_if<boost::icl::is_associative_element_container<std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::shared_ptr<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’
```

Answer (score 1):

In the section "Aggregate on Overlap" in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html#boost_icl.introduction.definition_and_basic_example.aggregate_on_overlap), it points out that the type mapped to needs to support set union.

The working version:

```
namespace icl = boost::icl;
using setOfPointers = std::set<std::shared_ptr<const std::string>>;
icl::interval_map<int, setOfPointers> party;
const auto mary = setOfPointers{std::make_shared<const std::string>("Mary")};
party += make_pair(icl::interval<int>::right_open(10, 16), mary);
```